# Массивы в objective-c

Tags: массивы, c

Как объявить символьный массив и числовой массив?
И как символ записать в символьный массив и как символ записать в числовой массив?

Comment: Почитайте, хотя бы чуть-чуть книжки, т.к. вопрос по примитивному синтаксису!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это вопрос не по Objective-C, а по C.

```
/* Статическое выделение памяти под элементы */
// инициализация
int iarray[100];  
char carray[100];
// обращение к элементам
iarray[1] = 41; 
carray[56] = 'a';

/* Динамически создаваемый массив */
// инициализация
int *dyn1 = malloc( sizeof(*dyn1) * 100 );  
char *dyn2 = malloc( sizeof(*dyn2) * 100 );
// обращение к элементам
dyn1[62] = 84; 
// обращение к элементам 2
*(dyn1 + 62) = 84;
```

Comment: а как в objective это сделать?

Comment: /* Статическое выделение памяти под элементы */
// инициализация
int iarray[100];  
char carray[100];
// обращение к элементам
iarray[1] = 41; 
carray[56] = 'a';


как эти строки в objective написать

Comment: прочитайте комментарий @aknew

Answer (score 0):

В массив нужно вносить объекты.
Для чисел это NSNumber, для символов NSString.

Comment: А как объявить массив?символьный и числовой типа int

Comment: @Sergey4590, вам нужен массив для типов `int` и `char`?

Comment: да просто объявление их с 50 элементами

Comment: если можно напишите кусочек кода)

Comment: так и объявите и просто как int numbers[50] и char symbols[50], obj-c же потомок с, причем с полной обратной совместимостью в отличие от плюсов

Comment: NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:[[[NSNumber]] numberWithInt:15]];

тоже самое можно проделать с символом. Дело в том, что в Objective-C нельзя добавить примитивы  типа int и char - только соотвествующие объекты.

Comment: @zhenyab на самом деле можно, если завернуть их при этом в обертку NSValue. Но, думаю, топикстартеру нужно не это.

Comment: Я предложил свой вариант решения поставленной задачи. Нахожу работу с соответсвуюшими объектами гораздо удобнее по многим причинам.
Одна из них та, что у массива есть масса полезных функций, а вторая, что приработе с объектами меньше шансов на создание "багов".

Comment: @zhenyab я с вами не спорю совершенно: в Objective-C объекты всегда превалируют перед примитивными типами данных. Просто @Sergey4590 интересуется именно стандартными сишными массивами, мало ли что ему нужно.

Comment: И я не спорю :)
Выбор решения остается за автором вопроса

Comment: Это точно, выбор за автором, только, судя по его вопросам, он еще и сам пока не знает что ему нужно :)